# Single-entity partitions in Azure Table

Tags: azure-table-storage

In an Azure table, having smaller partitions helps with load balancing Azure Table service. In my use case, there is no dependency between individual entities, whether I retrieve them or (re)write them. I am considering having single-entity partitions (that is, each partition would have one entity).

There is nothing I can find in Microsoft documentation (basically, [Table Storage Design Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide) and further literature referenced there) that would indicate down sides of this approach for my use case. I wonder if anyone here has had negative experience with this or similar approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only disadvantage of using single-entity partitions is that you can't leverage [**EntityGroupTransaction**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions) to insert/update entities in batch, which requires entities in the batch having the **same Partition Key**.

EntityGroupTransaction may achieve **better performance** than inserting/updating entities one by one, and operations within a batch are processed **atomically**.

Comment: Thank you very much, Zhaoxing Lu, for a quick answer! I have accepted it. Indeed, my user case as well as expected future use cases would not involve entity group transactions. I plan to go with single entity partitions.